# Django Admin UI add and edit objects in table form

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin

I have a Django app that displays tables on the user end of database queries. I would like the admin to be able to edit those models and objects in table form. Ex: click a value and type in the new value instead of having to click the object and hit save. I’m unsure if there is an easy/conventional way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like use [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Flexible solution for use django forms. Easy integrate ajax.